# JSON decode problems

Tags: php, javascript, json

When I post a text with Ajax, like this:

```
var text = encodeURIComponent(transtext);
```

and receive it with PHP:

```
$text=$_POST['text']
```

it seems that PHP automatically decodes the encoded string. Is there any way to avoid this?

Ok here is my original Json string that i want to post with ajax:

```
{"1":"\\"sdfsdfsdf" as&das&d ","2":"asdasd"}
```

I have to encodeURIComponent the string inside so i can post it json.strigify that dont encode &:

```
{"1":"%22asdasd%5C%22asdasd%22asdasd%26asdasd","2":"asdasd"}
```

But when i receive the string in PHP the " make fail the jsondecode because i get

```
POST={"1":""sdfsdfsdf" as&das&d ","2":"asdasd"}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: *"I have to encodeURIComponent the string inside"* — Of course not. What makes you believe this? Also, your "original JSON string" is not even a valid JS string to begin with, nor is it a valid JS object literal. As I said, *please post your code*.

Answer (score 1):

This function (`encodeURIComponent()`) does *not* produce JSON.

It produces an URL-encoded string, and these are decoded by the server automatically. I don't see why you would not want that.

URL-encoding is a pure transport encoding, its purpose in life is to make sure the data you send to a server is suitable for transfer via HTTP GET or POST, and that it is not garbled on its way. That the server decodes it for you before filling the `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_REQUEST` arrays is the right thing to do. It makes sure the data is in the same shape it was before it was sent from the client.

Comment: Because what i really post is a JSON in this way:  textnum_value[text_num]=encodeURIComponent(transtext);
 });

 var textnum_value=JSON.stringify(textnum_value);

Comment: @albanx: That's because you are doing it wrong. You are very likely double-encoding your data. Please post your JS-code above (the entire `post()` function call) and I can help you.

Comment: @albanx - so why didn't you say all that in the original question? Those are important details. Please expand the question to show us *all* the relevant code, as well as the input and output and how it differs from what you expect.